# Flutter how to pass data from qr_code_scanner back to the previous page and keep the context

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I am trying to add the [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) to a flutter project.

What I need to do is to press a Scan button on the `MainPage`, open the `QRScanner` page and then pass the result back to the `MainPage` in a `TextEditingController`.

I managed to do all that. However, when I pass the QR Scan result back to the `MainPage` I am replacing the entire `MainPage` context. I am also resetting the values for all other  controllers.

So once I finally do `Navigator.pop(context);` I am redirected back to the `QRScanner`, page instead of the Dashboard, which is what I need to do.

My question is, how can I pass the QR Scan result back without replacing the `MainPage` context? (At least I think this is the problem).

Main Page:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  late Store<AppState> store;
  final TextEditingController _name = new TextEditingController();
  late final TextEditingController _qrText = new TextEditingController();

  late QRScan? args;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    //In order to use the ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments outside build method
    final widgetsBinding = WidgetsBinding.instance;
    widgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback((callback) async {
      if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments != null) {
        args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as QRScan?;
        _qrText.text = args!.result!;
      }
    });
  }

  void nextButton() async {
    String name = _name.text;
    String uniqueId = _qrText.text;

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('url' ));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Do something
      Navigator.pop(context); //Here I get redirected back to /qrScanner Page instead of the Dashboard    
    } else {
      //Throw error message
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, StoreModel>(
        onInit: (str) => str.dispatch({ store = str, }),
        converter: (Store<AppState> store) => StoreModel.create(store),
        builder: (BuildContext context, StoreModel storeModel) => SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(),
              body: new Container(
                  child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
                    new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildTextFields()
                      ],
                    )
                  ])),
            )));
  }

  Widget _buildTextFields() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           new TextField(
              controller: _name,
            ),
            new TextField(
              controller: _qrText,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/qrScanner");
              },
              child: Text('Scan'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                nextButton(); //Here I get redirected back to QR Scan page instead of dashboard
              },
              child: Text('Insert'),
              )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

QR Scan Page:

```
class QRScanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const QRScanner({ Key ? key,  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _QRScannerState();
}

class _QRScannerState extends State<QRScanner> {
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller!.pauseCamera();
    }
    controller!.resumeCamera();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: _buildQrView(context)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        controller.pauseCamera();
        controller.resumeCamera();
        passToPreviousPage();
      });
    });
  }

  passToPreviousPage() {
    controller?.pauseCamera();

    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/mainPage",
        arguments: QRScan(result!.code));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class QRScan {
  final String? result;
  QRScan(this.result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push a route and use `await` to get the results. Then from the pushed page you can return the result with `Navigator.of(context).pop()`.

To do so, use this code when you push the route where you scan the QR code:

```
onPressed: () async {
  final qrCode = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/qrScanner");
},
```

Then in the page where you scan the QR code, return the scanned code with:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(result!.code);
```

You can also set the type that will be returned by the route:

```
final qrCode = await Navigator.pushNamed<Your_Type_Here>(context, "/qrScanner");
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! That's so much simpler than my method and the best thing is that it works!

Comment: You are welcome! I suggest that you consider [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner), this is the newer version from the same author.